# DNS Server returning same incorrect ip address for many queries

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I've inherited maintenance of a Windows Server 2012R2 dns server (I'm far from an expert on server maintenance), and it's started behaving very strangely. For a seemingly random selection of lookups it returns the following ip addresses:

```
156.154.175.217
156.154.176.217
```

I ran `netstat -a -n -o` on the machine to see if anything other than the dns service was listening on port 53 but found nothing. I checked the dns cache using `Show-DnsServerCache` and I can see that these erroneous records are turning up in the cache, so I'm fairly sure that the problem lies in the Windows DNS service rather than some malware intercepting dns queries.

The DNS server has `199.85.126.30` and `199.85.127.30` set up as forwarders which belong to Norton ConnectSafe. I've checked the root hint servers and they all seem to be pointing to the correct ip addresses according to [IANA](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers).

Basically, Has this dns server been pwned? Is there a way for me to trace where these seemingly malicious DNS records are comning from?

Comment: Try using a different set of forwarders and see if the problem ceases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking where this IP points to, it looks you are using some Norton firewall or similar, that for some DNS names will show a "protection" page: "this is a malicious page" or something like that.

It could also return the same IP for unknown or invalid DNSs.

So it does not look like pwned, but just the antivirus/firewall doing what it is designed for.

Comment: This appears correct. A few test transactions against 156.154.175.217:80 show that it results in a redirect to another webserver with the value of the host header added to the URL. The irony is that plugging 156.154.175.217 into your browser causes that IP to be set as the host header, which in turn causes Norton's website to report that 156.154.175.217 is a malicious IP...there really should have been a "this is why you are seeing this IP" page to capture that use case.

Comment: @AndrewB - That was one thing that confused me! It seems the Norton system was throwing up some false positives. Thanks